# Edit and save the json file data on the disk using Jquery Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I want to edit and write the data into the file which is on the disk and I want to save changes back to the same file using jquery. For this i have a button and textarea where I have edited the data and get the data before editing from json file as  html5 :

```js
function saveFile(data){
    
    $.getJSON("../custom_scripts/sub.json", function(data){
      
         var updatedData = $("#result").val();
         $("sub.json").replaceWith(updatedData);
        
    });
}
```

```html
  <form class="fileForm">
                <input type="file" value="Choose file" onchange="onFileSelected(event)">
                <br><br>
                <textarea id="result" rows="20" cols="100"></textarea>
                <button type="button" id="savable" class="btn btn-default" title="Save Changes" onclick="saveFile();"> Save</button>
</form>
```

After selecting the file the data gets edited and the additional data which I have entered is the updatedData but it

Comment: You can't write on client's disk !

Answer (score 1):

you can't write a JSON to a file on the clientside due to security reasons. (Otherwise you have access to the filesystems of your website's users.) You would have to use a server-side language for this, and store the file on the server-side.

Comment: The file which I have tried to edit is json file it is edited but couldn't save it :(

Answer (score 0):

For security, you can't write on client's disk.
The best way to save localy is to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).
You shoul read that [page from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FStorage) about webStorage.
  [some samples here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

```
var myContent = 'I am the content to save';
localStorage.setItem('mySaved', myContent);
```

and later to retrieve it :

```
 var myContent = localStorage.getItem('mySaved');
```

Comment: Yes..  I have used localstorage before to store the input field data as you mentioned :) Thank you. I want to add data externally not the hard coded :(

Comment: just go with it if you don't need to save server-side, it is a matter of design !

Comment: As it is a json file I want to add an item or many items each time i want to save so what can I do for that @Anonymous0day

Comment: use `localStorage.setItem('mySavedJson', JSON.stringify( myJSON ));` and  later `var mySavedJson = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('mySavedJson' ) );`